# Parametric Maximization of a function with indicator function

Tags: mathematical-optimization, parametric-functions

How is it possible to determine the maximum and maximizer of the following function? where `I(x>0) = 1 if x>0, otherwise 0`

```
f(x)= x-(x-c)(x-y-z)Boole[x>c]/v
```

with the assumptions that `0<=x<=v, v>0,c>0,y>0,z>0`. When I add the indicator function, I don't know why it cannot solve the problem.

```
Assumptions[v> 0, c > 0, y > 0, z > 0]
Maximize[{x - ((-c + x) (y + x - z)Boole[x>c] )/v,   x >= 0 && x <= v}, {x}]
```

As another question, I am wondering why in the answer of the following integration, the

```
Integrate[1/v, {x, 0, Max[y - c, 0]},  Assumptions -> y > 0 && c > 0 && v > 0]
```

Comment: Maybe `Integrate[1/v, {v, 1, Max[y - c, 0]}, 
 Assumptions -> y > 0 && c > 0 && v > 0]`

Answer (score 1):

Add condition into  `Maximize`

```
Maximize[{x - ((-c + x) (y + x - z) Boole[x > c])/v, x >= 0, x <= v, 
  v > 0, c > 0, y > 0, z > 0}, {x}]
```